# Use SATA cable on SAS Tape Drive

Tags: sas, tape

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I've an HBA similar to [this](http://www.9to5computer.com/dell/MEGARAIDSASHBA.jpg) with a SATAx4 adapter. 3 of those connectors are in Hard Disks drives, and the other is in a Quantum LTO-4 SAS Drive. That drive is damaged and I've bought a new HP drive with SAS too, but this new drive uses a [different conector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKHGS.jpg)

Then my question is: Can i cut the right side of the SATA cable and connect to new drive?. Both drives are SAS 3Gbps and the new drive has the same power cable as old drive too (besides SAS power cable).

Comment: something isnt right.  you should not be able to use a SAS drive on a SATA controller.  But you claim your old Quantum is SAS...  What is the exact model number for the SATA controller?

Comment: The HBA have a SAS1068E chipset, and is like this:
http://www.pc-pitstop.com/images/sas3442e_r_large.jpg


and the quantum drive is this:
http://www.quantum.com/serviceandsupport/softwareanddocumentationdownloads/lto-4hh/index.aspx


It uses a SATA cable, but interface is SAS (I can't use that drive in a normal SATA PC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've cutted the right side and is working fine:

http://s24.postimg.org/dd3t25vz9/DSC_0061.jpg

http://s24.postimg.org/obf2kckkl/DSC_0062.jpg

It don't have redundancy but is OK.

Greetings!!.

Comment: you are a brave man

Comment: Not so brave, I was thinking a long time and reading a lot of info about both ports, and how I was sure that both (controller and drive) are SAS then the most can happen is that drive will not work with that HBA. The only difference between SATA and SAS connector is plastic in the middle of SAS with a secondary connection (redundancy).